# Jstree: override function for paste

Tags: javascript, jstree

I use copy and paste in my Jstree instance but the default paste clears the copied nodes while I want to keep these in the buffer. 
If I modify te source code no problem but I'd rather not do that.

```
paste : function (obj, pos) {
            obj = this.get_node(obj);
            if(!obj || !ccp_mode || !ccp_mode.match(/^(copy_node|move_node)$/) || !ccp_node) { return false; }
            if(this[ccp_mode](ccp_node, obj, pos, false, false, false, ccp_inst)) {
                /**
                 * triggered when paste is invoked
                 * @event
                 * @name paste.jstree
                 * @param {String} parent the ID of the receiving node
                 * @param {Array} node the nodes in the buffer
                 * @param {String} mode the performed operation - "copy_node" or "move_node"
                 */
                this.trigger('paste', { "parent" : obj.id, "node" : ccp_node, "mode" : ccp_mode });
            }
            // what I changed by commenting out, need the buffer later
            // ccp_node = false;
            // ccp_mode = false;
            // ccp_inst = false;
        },
```

How can I override this function without modifying the source code ?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/daddie888/893659c2/7/) is a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself. Updated the fiddle.
I'll leave the question unanswered for the moment in case someone has a better solution.

Here is the code

```
    $.jstree.core.prototype.paste = function (obj, pos) {
        // need buffer otherwise ccp vars not known
        var buffer = this.get_buffer();
        ccp_mode = buffer.mode;
        ccp_node = buffer.node;
        ccp_inst = $('#jstree').jstree(true)
        obj = this.get_node(obj);
        if(!obj || !ccp_mode || !ccp_mode.match(/^(copy_node|move_node)$/) || !ccp_node) { return false; }
        if(this[ccp_mode](ccp_node, obj, pos, false, false, false, ccp_inst)) {
          this.trigger('paste', { "parent" : obj.id, "node" : ccp_node, "mode" : ccp_mode });
        }
      }
```